# Проблемы со знакомством SFML C++

Tags: c++, sfml

Всем привет, начал знакомиться с библиотекой SFML, стандартное окно запустить получилось.
Собственно не получается в это окно загрузить png картинку, при реализации этого процесса происходит зацикливание и программа виснет.

Вот код.

```
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML works!");
CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

/*
Image i;
i.loadFromFile("image/1232.png");

Texture t;
t.loadFromImage(i);                       // если убрать блок комментария,       то стандартное окно запускается.

Sprite s;
s.setTexture(t);
s.setPosition(50, 25);
*/
while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(s); // shape для стандарта.
    window.display();

}

return 0;
```

Comment: Ваш код точно не скомпилируется. Приведите минимальный полный компилируемый пример.

Comment: У меня работает, проверьте пути к картинке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас происходит не зацикливание, а "over-polling", окно слишком часто обновляется.

когда вы грузите текстуру и т.д., процессорное время ограничивается временем работы жесткого диска/памяти, когда вы не грузите текстуру и не делаете паузу (sleep в цикле), у вас просто получает максимально быстрый цикл, окно опрашивается со всей доступной процессу скоростью и выглядит зависшим. или даже не успевает отрисоваться